# Combine 2 navigation in mobile view, is it possible?

Tags: webview

I have 2 navigations which are inside of 2 different wrappers (e.g. one in header, one in footer). When I shrink the browser's size to mobile size I want to combine these 2 navigations. Is this feasible? 
I don't think this can be done by pure CSS. Not sure about PHP and JS?
Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 8000px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 500px
}
else {
    var $link1 = $('.menu-two .menu-two-link-one');
    $('.menu-one').append($link1);

    $('.menu-two .menu-two-link-one').remove();
}
```